# Is there a formula to sum numbers in the same cell as letters?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Is there a formula that I can use to place a letter in front of a number and still have it add?

I am working on a custom vacation and sick day spread sheet and I need to add a `v` if it is a vacation day and a `s` if it a sick day, ie `v7.5` or `s4`(the number represents number of hours)  and then I need it to add all the `s`'s and `v`'s separately.

Comment: Can you not use a separate column? It would be a lot cleaner than mixing data types and the workarounds you'd have to do to work with it.

Comment: If you are open to suggestive answer how to solve the issue, you may want to reword your question. As is, it narrows answers to only formulas. There may be other ways to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, the cleanest would be to add the v or s in another column as @Jonno says.

If no, I can think of 2 ways to do that:

a- You could use Number Formatting (right click, Format Cell, Number tab). Creating a  Custom format "v"#.0 and "s"#.0 to show v7.5 or s7.0 respectively.

b- you type the v or s in front of the number in the cell and then sum them using an array formula (holding CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER)

For example:

```
  |  A  |    B   |  C
 1|     |Days off|Check
 2|     | s1.0   | 1
 3|     | v1.5   | 1.5
 4|     | v1.5   | 1.5
 5|     | v3.0   | 3
 6|     | v2     | 2
 7|Total| 9      | 9
```

Formula in B7 => {=SUM(RIGHT(B2:B6,LEN(B2:B6)-1)+0)}  where you're doing the sum of the cells B2:B6 after removing the first character on the left (the +0 at the end is for Excel to convert the text string to number).

Answer (score 0):

I often use colors to differentiate various types of data. In a macro script, one can test for the background color of a cell, thus allowing the summation only of cells of a particular color. And perhaps another benefit would be the ability to see, at a glance, the amount of vacation or sick leave.

Comment: Although this is a great suggestion, it does not answer the question. It should be a comment.